# How to get order number which does not have a invoice number

Tags: mysql

How Can I find those order numbers which does not have invoice number? I did following query and it's showing all the order which has invoice number.How can I get all the order numbers which does not have invoice number?

```
SELECT invoice_tbl.increment_id AS 'Sales_Invoice_Number', order_tbl.increment_id AS   'Sales Order Number'
FROM magentodb.sales_flat_invoice AS invoice_tbl
JOIN magentodb.sales_flat_order AS order_tbl
  ON (order_tbl.entity_id = invoice_tbl.order_id)
WHERE order_tbl.created_at >= '2014-03-17'
  AND order_tbl.created_at <= '2014-05-07'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS clause.

```
SELECT  order_tbl.increment_id AS   'Sales Order Number'
FROM  magentodb.sales_flat_order AS order_tbl

WHERE order_tbl.created_at >= '2014-03-17'
  AND order_tbl.created_at <= '2014-05-07'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM magentodb.sales_flat_invoices
                  WHERE order_tbl.entity_id = order_id)
```

a `LEFT JOIN`  on `sales_flat_invoice`
with a `where` clause checking for null `order_id` could also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select order_tbl.increment_id AS 'Sales Order Number'
 FROM magentodb.sales_flat_order AS order_tbl
 WHERE order_tbl.increment_id NOT IN (select invoice_tbl.order_id 
                                      FROM magentodb.sales_flag_invoice AS invoice_tbl)
 AND order_tbl.created_at >= '2014-03-17'
 AND order_tbl.created_at <= '2014-05-07'
```

This will select all orders from the order_tbl that do not have an associated row in the invoice table, retaining your original filtering at the bottom of the query.